# Determining text color from the background color in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a color picker app in Swift and I need the text to adapt to the background color.

I have text on a UIView that is black by default and I would like it to turn lighter if there is a darker background color and to make the text darker if there is a lighter background color to make the text more readable.

Here are some screenshots:

Hardly readable text (First image)
[image: img]

Hardly readable text (Second image)
[image: img]

If it is possible I would be thankful for your reply.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
extension UIColor
{
    var isDarkColor: Bool {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
        return  lum < 0.50
    }
}
```

Which will calculate the luminance of the color and determine if it's above a certain threshold. Then say `myLabel.textColor = view.backgroundColor?.isDarkColor == true ? .white : .black`

Comment: If you're attempting to use this answer on a UIImage, you can use this framework to get the primary color of the image. https://github.com/jathu/UIImageColors

Comment: @Adrian Could you please let me know how can I use this framework? I am trying to adjust the text label colour depending upon the background Image view in Xcode. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I made a set of helpful extensions to go along with this https://gist.github.com/froggomad/cc4fa0f8e77bf548d23606bcd8290fce

Comment: Actually, that doesn't calculate the luminance. To calculate luminance correctly, you have to first linearize the data. That said, for the purposes of the question, this is good enough. It's just not luminance. Consider it a luminance proxy.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to @beyowulf 's answer, in SwiftUI, you can turn a **Color** into an **UIColor** and apply this.

```
extension UIColor
{
    var isDarkColor: Bool {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
        return  lum < 0.50
    }
}

extension Color{
    var isDarkColor : Bool {
        return UIColor(self).isDarkColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution that works with Dark and Light mode then use this extension.

```
extension UIColor {
    
    convenience init(
        light lightModeColor: @escaping @autoclosure () -> UIColor,
        dark darkModeColor: @escaping @autoclosure () -> UIColor
     ) {
        self.init { traitCollection in
            switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .light:
                return lightModeColor()
            case .dark:
                return darkModeColor()
            case .unspecified:
                return lightModeColor()
            @unknown default:
                return lightModeColor()
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// returns true if is a dark color
    var isDarkColor: Bool {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
        return  lum < 0.45
    }
    
    /// Generates contrasting color for dark and light userInterfaceStyles
    /// - Returns: UIColor.white for dark colors else return UIColor.black
    func contrastingColor() -> UIColor {
        let dark = self.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
        let light = self.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light))
        
        return UIColor(light: light.isDarkColor ? .white : .black,
                       dark: dark.isDarkColor ? .white : .black)
    }
    
}
```

### Demo:

Code reference [ContrastingText](https://github.com/kuttz/ContrastingText)

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor.black
let contrastingColor = backgroundColor.contrastingColor()
```

[image: GIF_description]